# PhoneGap: Camera API getPicture dialog enlarged

Tags: android, cordova

In Android 4.4, using Camera API getPicture API will result in a enlarged dialog.

The code is below:

```
        var sourceType = pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(fileURI) {
                        // Success callback
        }, function(message) {
                       // Fail callback
        }, {quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: sourceType, mediaType: mediaType, correctOrientation: false, saveToPhotoAlbum: true});
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect your issue is more linked with Astro file manager being called instead of the gallery. On my kitkat phone the same code opens the default gallery app and I have no issue.

Comment: But only Android 4.4 has such problem. There is no problem in Android 4.4 below. Which cordova version are u using?

Comment: And you also installed Astro for older android versions? I'm still using cordova 3.3. If you suspect a behaviour with the new webview in kitkat, you can try to set targetSDK to 18 instead of 19 (should make the new webview work in compatibility mode)

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue with any samsung device with kitkat. Changing source type to SAVEDPHOTOALBUM did nothing.

Comment: Also my problem has nothing to do with Astro.

Comment: Hi Justin, yes please find my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change android:anyDensity property in the AndroidManifest.xml from false to true fix the problem